# Set fallback font without having to declare every missing character

Tags: fonts, newunicodechar

I have the following code in my preamble to handle missing unicode characters in my CJKmainfont.

```
% Set Font.
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif} % Set serifed font to Calibri. Originally set to 'Times New Roman', but it cannot display certain characters such as ①②③.

\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK TC}
\setCJKsansfont{Noto Sans CJK TC} % Set Chinese font. NOTE: Remember to append CJK before of the font class. CJK HAS to be there for the font to show.
\setCJKmonofont{Noto Sans Mono TC}

% Set fallback fonts for ㊀ characters.

\newunicodechar{㊀}{{\ttfamily ㊀}}
\newunicodechar{㊁}{{\ttfamily ㊁}}
\newunicodechar{㊂}{{\ttfamily ㊂}}
\newunicodechar{㊃}{{\ttfamily ㊃}}
\newunicodechar{㊄}{{\ttfamily ㊄}}
\newunicodechar{㊅}{{\ttfamily ㊅}}
\newunicodechar{㊆}{{\ttfamily ㊆}}
\newunicodechar{㊇}{{\ttfamily ㊇}}
\newunicodechar{㊈}{{\ttfamily ㊈}}
\newunicodechar{㊉}{{\ttfamily ㊉}}
\newunicodechar{・}{{\ttfamily ・}}

% Rare Characters

\newCJKfontfamily\rarechar{HanaMinB}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
% \newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
% \newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
% \newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
% \newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
% \newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
% \newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
% \newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
% \newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
% \newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
% \newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}


% Set fallback fonts for ① characters.

\newunicodechar{①}{{\sffamily ①}}
\newunicodechar{②}{{\sffamily ②}}
\newunicodechar{③}{{\sffamily ③}}
\newunicodechar{④}{{\sffamily ④}}
\newunicodechar{⑤}{{\sffamily ⑤}}
\newunicodechar{⑥}{{\sffamily ⑥}}
\newunicodechar{⑦}{{\sffamily ⑦}}
\newunicodechar{⑧}{{\sffamily ⑧}}
\newunicodechar{⑨}{{\sffamily ⑨}}
\newunicodechar{⑩}{{\sffamily ⑩}}
\newunicodechar{✔}{{\sffamily ✔}}
\newunicodechar{Ⓐ}{{\sffamily Ⓐ}}
\newunicodechar{Ⓑ}{{\sffamily Ⓑ}}
\newunicodechar{Ⓒ}{{\sffamily Ⓒ}}
```

It is super tedious to have to declare a newunicodechar everytime a rare character is used in writing.

Also, I run into `TeX capacity exceeded` error after a fair bit of `newunicodechar` declarations. (***Side-note***: The error is caused by calling the same `newunicodechar` twice, which is somewhat inevitable as the list gets longer.)

Is there a way to avoid this hassle?

I use XeLaTeX to compile the typesetting.

---

## Sample Document:

```
% Intended LaTeX compiler: xelatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{ctexart}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

% Set Paper Size, Page Layout (another variable is 'bindingoffset')
\usepackage[margin = 1.5in, paper = a4paper, inner = 2.5cm,
outer = 2.5cm, top = 3cm, bottom = 2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec} % packages for title and section-heading font setting.
\usepackage{newunicodechar} % custom fallback font for certain unicode characters.

% Set Font.
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK TC}
\setCJKsansfont{Noto Sans CJK TC} % Set Chinese font. NOTE: Remember to append CJK before of the font class. CJK HAS to be there for the font to show.
\setCJKmonofont{Noto Sans Mono CJK TC}

% Set fallback fonts for ㊀ characters.

\newunicodechar{㊀}{{\ttfamily ㊀}}
\newunicodechar{㊁}{{\ttfamily ㊁}}
\newunicodechar{㊂}{{\ttfamily ㊂}}
\newunicodechar{㊃}{{\ttfamily ㊃}}
\newunicodechar{㊄}{{\ttfamily ㊄}}
\newunicodechar{㊅}{{\ttfamily ㊅}}
\newunicodechar{㊆}{{\ttfamily ㊆}}
\newunicodechar{㊇}{{\ttfamily ㊇}}
\newunicodechar{㊈}{{\ttfamily ㊈}}
\newunicodechar{㊉}{{\ttfamily ㊉}}
\newunicodechar{・}{{\ttfamily ・}}

\newCJKfontfamily\rarechar{HanaMinB}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}

\begin{document}

①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩
㊀㊁㊂㊃㊄㊅㊆㊇㊈㊉


\end{document}
```

Comment: which engine do you use?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, xelatex

Comment: Also, I run into `TeX capacity exceeded` error after a fair bit of `newunicodechar` declarations.

Comment: you should try to make examples that other can actually test without to much effort (I don't have all your fonts)  and don't contain all sort of unrelated code.

Comment: Purged most of the unrelated code in the sample document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : I've cleaned up the code and switched to Noto font, which is freely [available](https://www.google.com/get/noto/). The Hanazono font for rare characters can be found over [here](https://zh-tw.osdn.net/frs/redir.php?m=ipconnect&f=hanazono-font%2F64385%2Fhanazono-20160201.zip).

Comment: well you already found out why it looped. And regarding the chars: with lualatex you could define a fallback font, but with xelatex your method is imho fine, if your rare chars are all in the same unicode block you could write a loop to define them all in one go).

Comment: How do we do that? Say, I'd like to loop through all the Ext-B CJK characters.